# Why when I click on the Start button it disables the Labels and the color of the RichTextBox and ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program written in C#, when I click on the Start button it disables all the GroupBoxes and all the buttons except the Stop button but something strange happens.

1/ All the labels (circled in pink on the picture) which are normally white but after the click on the Start button they become black

The "RichTextBox" and the "ComboBox" (circled in green on the picture) which are normally black background color but they also change color when I click on the Start button to become white

2/ Another thing, do you know why the warning message (circled in blue on the picture) repeats itself indefinitely at each data refresh? However the information message which is underneath written in green is displayed only once
(yet the code of the 2 messages are similar)

Here is the code to disable the GroupBox and buttons:

```
  private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.grSettings.Enabled = false;
       this.grTelegramSetting.Enabled = false;
       this.grTradeSetting.Enabled = false;
       this.grAccountSetting.Enabled = false;
       this.btnCreateOrder.Enabled = false;
       this.cbCheckBlance.Enabled = false;
       this.btnClosePositionTest.Enabled = false;
       this.btnStart.Enabled = false;
       this.btnStop.Enabled = true;
   }
```

Here is the code of the warning messages:

```
if (!tradeSetting.FlagAutoCreateOrderDCA)
   FMain.Log.Warn((object)"La création de l'ordre DCA arrêter, ne
```

pas activer le DCA auto.");

Here is the code of the info messages:

```
 try
 {
   FMain.Log.Info((object)"Début de la vérification auto.");
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When you disable a _Container_ control like the `GroupBox`, its `Controls` are disabled too, and that's how the renderers of the mentioned controls render the disabled state. So, and for example, instead of disabling the containers, loop their `Controls` collections to skip the labels. As for `2/` You need to post the relevant code. And why are you doing this `(object)"La,,,"` ? What happens if you omit `(object)` ?

Comment: Thank you, how do you manage to loop their Controls collections to skip the labels ?
When I delete (object) I always have the same problem

Comment: ex. `foreach (var c in grSettings.Controls.OfType<Control>()) if (!(c is Label)) c.Enabled = false;`. Get rid of `(object)`. It has nothing to do with the problem here.

Comment: Great thanks... so I tried and I still have the same behavior

Comment: Don't disable the group boxes! `grSettings`, `grTelegramSetting` ...etc. For the `RichTextBox`, set the `ReadOnly` property to `true` instead of disabling the control to have the same background color.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it really helps... instead of disabling the groupbox (as you said) I disable when clicking on Start only the options and it works perfectly...

Why can't I set the "ComboBox" to read only?

Comment: No such feature in WinForms ComboBox. You can host a WPF ComboBox which supports `IsReadOnly`, `IsEditable` features. You need to try that and ask a new question including what you have tried if you still need a hand. Sticking with WinForms, you can handle the `KeyPress` event to `e.Handled = true;` and the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event to `YourComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1`. Both to prevent entering text (if ComboBoxStyle.DropDown) and changing the selection. Alternatively, create your own ComboBox and draw it as you wish. Big story.